# React Native App “Unfortunately Stops" on start in Android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

My App “Unfortunately Stops" on start in Android emulator, after `react-native-fbsdk` package installing and configuring.

I have installed this package as guided in the documentation.

On `adb logcat` I got this log.

```
09-18 17:02:05.251  1545  1557 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.exampleproject/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10008 on display 0
09-18 17:02:05.489  1545  2041 I ActivityManager: Start proc 29665:com.exampleproject/u0a67 for activity com.exampleproject/.MainActivity
09-18 17:02:05.518 29665 29665 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.exampleproject, PID: 29665
09-18 17:02:05.518 29665 29665 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.exampleproject.MainApplication: A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
09-18 17:02:05.518 29665 29665 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.exampleproject.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:56)
09-18 17:02:05.732  1545  3286 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.exampleproject/.MainActivity
09-18 17:02:06.315  1545  1559 W ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{47cc657 u0 com.exampleproject/.MainActivity t51 f}
09-18 17:02:17.062  1545  1559 W ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{47cc657 u0 com.exampleproject/.MainActivity t51 f}
```

As I understand this log is says `A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml`. I have set facebook app correctly.

I have added this below line in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">realFBappID</string>
```

And Added a meta-data element to the application element

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
    ...
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    ...
</application>
```

Every thing seems correct to me. Even though app is not working. Please guide what could the issue here....

Answer (score 0):

create app at facebook and add it's id  [enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) 
 in `strings.xml`

```
<resources>
   <string name="facebook_app_id">someid...</string> // you need to add real Facebook app id and wrap it in resources
</resources>
```

in android

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
  android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, it is real Facebook id, I have used `someid...` as example. Here I have just not disclosed the real ID

Comment: did you changed @string/facebook_app_id

Comment: I have already followed the link you have suggested here. And all configuration is according to this source.

Comment: try to wrap <string> with <resources> in strings.xml

Comment: `@string/facebook_app_id` this will pick the value from the strings.xml file. where I have used the App id. And I have already tried it by replacing it with hard code Facebook real ID. It has not worked

Comment: did you wrap<string> with <resources> in strings.xml ?